# Decompress zlib encoded nsdata

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, zlib

I am trying to decompress some zlib encoded data that I am downloading using ASIHTTPRequest wrapper.

This is what I have so far.. pretty much just getting the data in and now I was hoping for some help to start the decompression process.

```
- (IBAction)sendHttpsRequest
{   

    //Set request address
    NSMutableString *databaseURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"https://192.168.17.36:443"];

    //call ASIHTTP delegates (Used to connect to database)
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:databaseURL];

    //This sets up all other request
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
    [request setPostValue:@"ClientDataSet.xml" forKey:@"filename"];  
    [request startSynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    responseData = [request responseData]; //Pass requested data from server over to NSData variable..

//Is this where I have to think about decompression? or do I pass this data out to another method?
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    self.hudCheck = NO;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(stopAnimating) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

So pretty much I am up to the decompression stage however I am not sure which functions/methods etc I need to use to decompress this data. I have only ever attempted this with gzip which was comparatively easy as the ASI wrapper handles everything itself.

However due to circumstances outside my control the data I am now getting is zlib encoded.. So any functions, methods or examples you can tell me about that will help my cause would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Moving forward from @Caleb response I have added 
include "zlib.h" to my file and now have access to this frameworks methods. One of which is the inflate() method.. however I am not sure what parameters need to be entered into it? any ideas?.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you had a look at [the example](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html) on the zlib web site? `inflateInit()`, `inflate()`, and `inflateEnd()` look like (almost) all you need.

You'll want to apply the lesson from the example in your `-requestFinished:` method. In other words, you'll first download all the compressed data, and only then try to decompress it. It's probably possible to decompress as you download, but that'll be more complicated without being more helpful.

**Update:** To answer your follow-up question, the two parameters you need to pass into `inflate()` are the z_stream (which you will have initialized previously using `inflateInit()`) and a flush option. The example uses Z_NO_FLUSH -- you'll have to read a bit to find out what other options are possible.

My advice is to take the `inf()` function from the example, minus all the interspersed explanatory text, and paste it into your code. Next, convert it to read from your NSData and write to an NSMutableData, possibly using NSInputStream and NSOutputStream as suggested in my comment below. That should give you a function to which you can pass a NSData containing compressed data and which will return a NSMutableData containing the uncompressed data.

Comment: Yes I saw that but I thought I was looking at a C++ example and was not sure how to get this to work with what I am doing. Just I just need to add #include "zlib.h" then I can call inFlate on my NSData object?

Comment: Cool, I am just tring to figure out now what parameters are supposed to be enerted into inflate(__, __)

Comment: The example is in plain old C. It's heavily annotated, so read through it a few times and make sure you understand it first. The `inf()` function in the example reads and writes from/to files; you'll probably want to adapt it to read from your NSData and write to a NSMutableData that you provide. It's not hard to replace the `fread()` and `fwrite()` calls with calls to NS[Mutable]Data, but you might want to use NSInputStream and NSOutputStream to make things even easier. Conceptually, NS[Input|Output]Stream work a lot like FILE* -- just buffers that you read or write sequentially.

Comment: Cool thanks for all the help man.. Think this might be abit outside my current set of skills.. Will keep reading the example and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this NSData category:  http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory

Using this you can simply write:

```
   uncompressedResponseData = [[request responseData] zlibInflate];
```

Comment: going to test this in the morning! thanks very much will mark once I have tested it!!! again thanks heaps for this.

Comment: Im just reading though it properly now and have found two entries -Added deflate method for zlib; works but not thoroughly tested; probably best suited for small blocks of data. Would appreciate feedback/code review/improvement/etc. -Seb

Added full support for gzip inflate/deflate. Mostly a copy of the zlib methods, with the proper window size change for gzip.

and the last time this library was updated was back in 2009 so not sure if I should use this or not... I will keep reading etc, and decide soon.

Answer (score 0):

See http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2013/03/14/code-snippet-decompressing-a-gzipped-buffer/

This is a great example of zlib.h for iOS. Very clear and concise. No 3rd party library required.